# how can I jump to the Order Review Step in Magento onepage checkout

Tags: javascript, php, magento, onepage-checkout

How can I make jump to the last step (order review)  in Magento ONEPAGE checkout. The billing address, shipping address, shipping method, payment method are auto populated from the quote.

I want to provide a link to the customer that redirects the customer to the onepage checkout page. The details of billing address and shipping address are taken from the quote and auto populated. but customer should be taken to the last step (order review).

I tried using javascript:

```
function skipToReview(){
   billing.save();
   setTimeout(function(){shipping.save();},3000);
   setTimeout(function(){shippingMethod.save();},6000);
   setTimeout(function(){
        var method=document.getElementById('gwl_method_code').value;
        document.getElementById('p_method_'+method).checked="true";
    },9000);
    setTimeout(function(){payment.save();},10000);
}
```

but I don't want to set the time as it sometimes calls the next function before the previous one executes completely.

Is there a way to call a predefined javascript function only after the previous one executes?